# Timber feature-matching based on deep learning

Tags: feature-extraction

How to extract contour features for each timber which mainly depends on the diameter of the end face to determine the price?How to recognise the timber when scanning one of a pile of timber with a mobile phone, and then read out all the information corresponding to that?

Could you please give the technical route to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) As your question is currently written, it is difficult to answer. Is there anything you have tried to do so far? If so, please _edit_ your question and describe those attempts and why they have failed. Also, how are you scanning the pile of wood? Are you taking pictures? Are you using the iPhone LiDAR?

Comment: Concerning your particular application, there's a commercial product called WoodCa available (see [this press release in German](https://www.iabg.de/news-termine/details/iabg-entwickelt-app-fuer-die-digitale-und-mobile-holzvermessung/). It takes pictures of piles of wood and detects the faces of trees. _(Note: I used to work with IABG, the manufacturer of WoodCa but am not affiliated with them anymore.)_